# Creating an equilateral triangle for given two points in the plane - Python

Tags: python-3.x, euclidean-distance

I have two points `X = (x1,y1)` and `Y=(x2,y2)` in the Cartesian plane. I need to find the third point `Z = (x,y)` such that these three points make an equilateral triangle.

I'm calculating the Euclidean distance between two points using the following code sample:

```
def distance(points, i, j):
dx = points[i][0] - points[j][0]
dy = points[i][1] - points[j][1]
return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

In theory, I need to equate the distances of `XZ` and `YZ` to `XY`.This gives us two possible answers and I need them both too. But I'm having a difficulty in initiating the point `Z` in my code. Can someone please help me with this? 
The following is a sample of what I tried.

```
L = [0, 6]  #known two points
d= distance(points, L[0], L[1])
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
newpoint = x,y   #coordintes of the third point of the triangle
f1 = distance(points, L[0], newpoint)
f2 = distance(points, L[1], newpoint)
print(nsolve((f1, f2), (x, y), (d,d)))
```

But this returns the following error:

```
 File "/Users/*.py", line 99, in <module>
    f1 = distance(points, L[0], newpoint)

  File "/Users/*.py", line 36, in distance
    dx = points[i][0] - points[j][0]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: Equilateral triangles have 60°angle. Use trigonometry. You have distance and angle, you can get position.

Comment: Note: `math.hypot(dx, dy)` is the equivalent to the `math.sqrt(...)` call. @politinsa you don't need trig for this problem because you know that the points are the perpendiculars from the middle of the XY vector at a distance of `math.sqrt(distance()**2 - (distance()/2)**2) == math.sqrt(3)*distance()/2` [Pythagoras theorem]

Comment: Why are you passing a `point` as the 3rd argument to `distance()`, it is meant to be an index into the list of points, assume you need to add `newpoint` to points and then pass the appropriate index, or change your `distance()` function.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks for your comment!  I'm calculating the Euclidean distance of two sides and equating that to the known distance (d). ` newpoint ` is the coordinates of the third vertex of the triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the third point of a equilateral triangle doesn't need anything really complicated, simply find the mid-point between `X` and `Y`, you know that this forms a right angle to point `Z` so just map to the origin, multiply by `sqrt(3)` (simplification of Pythagoras theory for equilateral triangles) and rotate 90 degrees in both directions (`x,y => y,-x`, `x,y => -y,x`), and map back, e.g.:

```
X, Y = (1,1), (2,1)
M = (X[0]+Y[0])/2, (X[1]+Y[1])/2            # Mid point
O = (X[0]-M[0])*3**0.5, (X[1]-M[1])*3**0.5  # Map to origin, multiply sqrt(3)

In []:
M[0]+O[1], M[1]-O[0]                        # Rotate 90 (y,-x), map back

Out[]:
(1.5, 1.8660254037844386)

In []:
M[0]-O[1], M[1]+O[0]                        # Rotate -90 (-y,x), map back

Out[]:
(1.5, 0.1339745962155614)
```

You can do this in numpy:

```
X, Y = np.array([1,1]), np.array([2,1])
M = (X + Y) / 2
O = (X - M) * 3**0.5
t = np.array([[0, -1], [1, 0]])   # 90 degree transformation matrix

In []:
M + O @ t

Out[]:
array([1.5      , 1.8660254])

In []:
M + O @ t.T                       # the transpose gives -90

Out[]:
array([1.5      , 0.1339746])
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to get the third vertex, you could just rotate the point `(x2, y2)` by `60` degrees around point `(x1, y1)`. The other admissible solution would be obtained with a rotation by `-60` degrees, i.e., in the opposite direction.

```
import math


def get_point(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    #express coordinates of the point (x2, y2) with respect to point (x1, y1)
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1

    alpha = 60./180*math.pi
    #rotate the displacement vector and add the result back to the original point
    xp = x1 + math.cos( alpha)*dx + math.sin(alpha)*dy
    yp = y1 + math.sin(-alpha)*dx + math.cos(alpha)*dy

    return (xp, yp)


print(get_point(1, 1, 2, 1))
# (1.5, 0.1339745962155614)
```